# apache httpclient clientprotocol classnotfoundexception when gradle with program args

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-test

I am trying to run `gradlew test -Penv="envLocal"`

this is throwing ClassNotFound : ClientProtocolException but without -Penv its working well.

Can you someone help with this issue?

Running spring test

Comment: Arbitrary commands within a build environment are quite hard to reproduce. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it was due to different configurations for different environment.